# .cpp and .h files of new classes are not showing in Ubuntu SDK tree

Tags: application-development, c++, ubuntu-sdk

I've added new classes to my project via `Ctrl-N` >> `C++` >> `C++ Class`.

However, after the files are added to my `models`/`my-project` folder, it does not show up on the tree in Ubuntu SDK.

Why is this? And how can I make my files show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CMakeLists.txt` file within the `backend` folder needs to be modified.

Add `modules/my-project/my-class.cpp` to 'set'.